# Can't access docker container via domain name, but able by IP address

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a problem with Nginx proxy manager, we dockerize a Vue.js app and running it on local, but can't assign domain name to it.

I watched some YouTube video and not work for me, at the moment, I can access by the IP address rather than the domain name.

Domain set up on Cloudflare, and some other subdomain working fine, and I setup proxy.bcsystems.nz on NPM, it's working fine

[image: NPM]
[image: Portainer]

```
version: "3"

services:

postgres:

environment:

- TZ=Pacific/Auckland

- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***

- POSTGRES_DB=***

image: postgres:11.17-alpine

restart: always

volumes:

- ./postgres/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

- ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

backend:

build:

context: ./backend

restart: always

environment:

- TZ=Pacific/Auckland

ports:

- "8345:8080"

depends_on:

- postgres

links:

- postgresversion: "3"

services:

postgres:

environment:

- TZ=Pacific/Auckland

- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***

- POSTGRES_DB=***

image: postgres:11.17-alpine

restart: always

volumes:

- ./postgres/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

- ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

backend:

build:

context: ./backend

restart: always

environment:

- TZ=Pacific/Auckland

ports:

- "8345:8080"

depends_on:

- postgres

links:

- postgres
```

tried use docker Internal ip address 172.x.x.x
tried apply new SSL cert in NPM